# Pass 'use' objects to Routes with Slim Framework

Tags: php, pdo, frameworks, routes, slim

I have just began using Slim Framework for a very basic REST API project and it is absolutely perfect for my needs. I am however trying to determine how to use both route groups in combination with passing objects to the routes through 'use'.

How can I pass the $app instance among other objects (such as $db) to my route functions? I can circumvent this problem by fetching $app within the function using `$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();` but need to pass a database object as well. For the sake of progress I am currently just using it in a GLOBAL variable but would like to find a proper way if possible.

```
// create new Slim instance
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->contentType('application/json');

$app->group('/core', function() use($app)
{
    $app->group('/device', function() use($app)
    {
        $app->get( '/getId/:id', 'getDeviceID' );
    });
});

function getDeviceID($id)
{
    $app->response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically I use a global variable. I think it's the simplest way to do this.

However you could simply inject it in your `$app` instance:

```
$app->db = new YourAmazingDb();
```

and then use it:

```
function getDeviceID($id)
{
  $device = $app->db->getDevice($id);
  //More business here with $device
  $app->response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
}
```

Comment: I think I will stick with using a global variable for this case. I did not even think about injecting it into the $app instance though, that is a great alternative approach. Thank you!